# Trouble linking C++ with Xcode 5

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang, llvm

So I have this legacy project, which I am trying to bring to iOS 7 and Xcode 5. And by legacy, I mean real legacy. Like 2004 legacy.

Anyhow, I am trying to build this thing, and it spits out a few libraries, including some common third party libs. When linking, I get errors like these:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture ${arch}:
  "google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytes(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)"
```

Upon examination with `nm`, the old (arm only) binary library still included in the project contains this:

```
         U __ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteBytesEiRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
00000a8c T __ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteBytesEiRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
00002b28 S __ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteBytesEiRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE.eh</code>
```

The new library (universal), created when I run the project through Xcode 5 (and thus, clang/llvm) contains this:

```
         U __ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteBytesEiRKSsPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
00000514 T __ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteBytesEiRKSsPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE
00000b2c S __ZN6google8protobuf8internal14WireFormatLite10WriteBytesEiRKSsPNS0_2io17CodedOutputStreamE.eh
```

To me, it looks like the parameters are missing in the mangled name.

Is this normal and I need to look somewhere else?

Or if this is the problem: Any idea how to solve it?

EDIT: I mixed up OLD and NEW. I left the original post unchanged

Answer (score 2):

The old, arm only libary seems to indicate:

```
google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytes(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)
```

Which has all the hallmarks of being compiled with libstdc++.

The new universal library indicates:

```
google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytes(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)
```

This has all the hallmarks of being compiled with libc++

Your link error indicates that there is a problem finding:

```
 google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytes(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)
```

This would be the case if the code linking to the library was compiled using `libstdc++` and, because your new universal library is compiled using `libc++` the code will not link.

You have to compile **everything** with the same libc++/libstdc++ support, you cannot mix and match as they will refuse to link. Make sure that every element in your project is compiled using the same C++ Standard Library and the link error should be resolved.

In general, demangling the symbols (using `c++filt`) allows you to see the proper signatures, and in the case of this code, once you start seeing `std::__1::` in the symbols, it indicates that the library was compiled using `libc++`, and when you see the link failing with unadorned `std::` symbols (i.e. without the inner `__1::`), then it indicates that the item performing the linking is using `libstdc++`.

Comment: I am sorry, I seem to have mixed up old and new, which makes sense then I guess. That would probably indicate that the App I am linking against is still linking libstdc++, right?

Comment: It seems more likely that if you swapped around the mentioning of old and new, it indicates that the protobuf based library has now been built with libc++ and your app is being built with libstdc++ - this is what the erroneous link line is claiming. The signatures for linking in the app seem to indicate that this is the issue (I'll update the answer once I'm back from my run)

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps mixing and matching SDKs or compilers? Name mangling might differ between compilers. The only other thing I know that might affect name mangling is the 'extern "C"' keyword, but that usually turns it off completely, so I don't think that's it.

So, if the old code was still built with GCC 2.x and your new code is clang-built, they probably just mangle differently.

Does the error message really say $(arch) ? Not a particular architecture? If it gave a concrete architecture, I'd expect that you have one project that builds e.g. for arm5 and arm6, linking in a library that only has one of these architectures. Then it usually complains about the symbols in that library not being available, I think.

Comment: (No, I put in ${arch} to indicate it fails for both arm and x86}